# Combining multiple flowables

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, reactive-streams

I am migrating my project from Spring to Ktor, and decided to replace the implementation of reactive streams which was initially Reactor to RxJava 2. Although I faced some problem when trying to combine multiple streams into single one at the end of the reactive pipeline. Here it is how it looks like:

```
internal interface Aggregator {
    fun acquireSomethingFromSomewhere(keyword: String): Flowable<Some>
}

fun acquireSomething(keyword: String) = Flowable
    .fromIterable(aggregators)
    .map { it.acquireSomethingFromSomewhere(keyword) }
    .flatMap { ??? }
```

The thing is, each call of `acquireSomethingFromSomewhere` returns `Flowable<Some>`, is there any operator which could help me combine them in the one stream at the end? In Reactor I just used:

```
fun acquireSomething(keyword: String) = Flux
    .fromIterable(aggregators)
    .map { it.acquireSomethingFromSomewhere(keyword) }
    .flatMap { Flux.concat(it) }
```

But in RxJava I can't find any operator which could solve my problem, as each of them takes `Publisher` as an argument, and `Flowable` does not implement it.

Comment: Does `.flatMap { it.acquireSomethingFromSomewhere(keyword) }` suit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if the function you provide in `map` returns a `Flowable`, you will end up with nested Flowables (a.k.a. `Flowable<Flowable<T>>`), which is not what you probably want. This is because the `map` function only transform the element inside the container `(T) -> R` (in this case the container is `Flowable`). In your case, you want to transform the element inside the first container returning a new container `(T) -> Flowable<R>`, this function is called [`flatMap`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables#flatmap). In the case of **Rx** you have more functions (operators) depending on their behavior, like [`concatMap`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables#concatmap) and [`switchMap`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables#switchmap), but the signatures are the same.

**Example**

```
fun acquireSomething(keyword: String) = Flowable
    .fromIterable(aggregators)
    .flatMap { it.acquireSomethingFromSomewhere(keyword) }
```

**PS**

If you want to know more about the theory behind, you can follow [Arrow-kt](https://arrow-kt.io/) documentation of [Functor](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/arrow/typeclasses/functor/) and [Monad](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/arrow/typeclasses/monad/)